# Math Riddle Involving Birthdays

Tags: calendar-computations

So someone asked me the following riddle:

If a girl is born in the 19th century, and on her first birthday she is 8. How is this possible? I think it's a simple mathematics problem but I can't find a way to figure it out.

Comment: Presumably something to do with February 29?

Comment: @Zev: Feb 29, 1896, to be precise.

Comment: (This is not a mathematics question, just one involving knowing when [leap years](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year) occur.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If she was born on February 29, 1896, then the next time February 29 came around was in 1904 (due to the 100-year rule of the Gregorian Calendar, 1900 was not a leap year). That is, on her first "birthday", she was 8 years old.

(Cue *Pirates of Penzance*)

Comment: Sweet nice - I wasn't aware of that rule.

Comment: @eWizardII: Under the Gregorian Calendar, years divisible by 4 are leap years, unless they are multiples of 100, unless they are multiples of 400; which is why 1700, 1800, and 1900 were not leap years, but 2000 was; 2100, 2200, and 2300 will not be leap years, but 2400 will.